# Cloudrun Django+Terraform / 404 error on app URL

Tags: django, google-cloud-run

I just followed this tutorial : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/serverless-expeditions/tree/main/cloud-run-django-terraform

I've done :

- gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild-migrate.yaml
- terraform apply -var project=$PROJECT_ID

My database was created. Service was pushed online well and I've got a service_url.
When I access it, it shows a 404 error. Even if try to access the /admin page, it just returns a 500 error with no explanation in the log journal (or I didn't find it).

When I try to runserver on localhost with sql_cloud_proxy, Django works perfectly. It's just a Django basic project showing hello on homepage.

I don't get it.

Here's my settings.py file :

```
import io
import os
from pathlib import Path

import environ
import google.auth
from google.cloud import secretmanager

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

env = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, False))
env_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env")

# Attempt to load the Project ID into the environment, safely failing on error.
try:
    _, os.environ["GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT"] = google.auth.default()
except google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError:
    pass

if os.path.isfile(env_file):
    # Use a local secret file, if provided
    env.read_env(env_file)
elif os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT", None):
    # Pull secrets from Secret Manager
    project_id = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT")

    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
    settings_name = os.environ.get("SETTINGS_NAME", "django_settings")
    name = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{settings_name}/versions/latest"
    payload = client.access_secret_version(name=name).payload.data.decode("UTF-8")

    env.read_env(io.StringIO(payload))
else:
    raise Exception("No local .env or GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT detected. No secrets found.")

SECRET_KEY = env("SECRET_KEY")

# DEBUG = env("DEBUG")
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "gadsapimonitor",
    "storages",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "gadsapimonitor.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "gadsapimonitor.wsgi.application"

# Use django-environ to parse DATABASE_URL from secrets
DATABASES = {"default": env.db()}

# If using Cloud SQL Auth Proxy, change the database values accordingly.
if os.environ.get("USE_CLOUD_SQL_AUTH_PROXY"):
    DATABASES["default"]["HOST"] = "127.0.0.1"
    DATABASES["default"]["PORT"] = 5432
else:
    DATABASES["default"]["HOST"] = "127.0.0.1"
    DATABASES["default"]["PORT"] = 5432

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = "fr-fr"
TIME_ZONE = "UTC"
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True


STATIC_ROOT = "/static/"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

# Define static storage via django-storages[google]
if env("GS_BUCKET_NAME"):
    GS_BUCKET_NAME = env("GS_BUCKET_NAME")
    STATICFILES_DIRS = []
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"
    GS_DEFAULT_ACL = "publicRead"

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
```

My Dockerfile :

```
# Use an official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.9-slim

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# Install dependencies.
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . .

# Service must listen to $PORT environment variable.
# This default value facilitates local development.
ENV PORT 8080

# Setting this ensures print statements and log messages
# promptly appear in Cloud Logging.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED TRUE

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 myapp.wsgi:application
```

I've tried to set DEBUG=True to show something but nothing changed.

Is someone has an idea to fix this issue ?

Many thanks,

EDIT : Log

```
{
httpRequest: {10}
insertId: "61bd16c6000351727a95b33c"
labels: {
instanceId: "00bf4bf02de1a8b1de1bec9253140c16ac133ee11a6264fd4b1ce063dee5b680b3e567f87e6e1ec1a40e92314275ca0dac93e25dc02cded8677918"
}
logName: "projects/gaxxxxxxxtor-xxxx420/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests"
receiveTimestamp: "2021-12-17T23:01:26.220970335Z"
resource: {
labels: {
configuration_name: "gaxxxxxxxtor-xxxx420"
location: "europe-west4"
project_id: "gaxxxxxxxtor-xxxx420"
revision_name: "gaxxxxxxxtor-xxxx420-kw9ld"
service_name: "gaxxxxxxxtor-xxxx420"
}
type: "cloud_run_revision"
}
severity: "ERROR"
timestamp: "2021-12-17T23:01:26.217458Z"
trace: "projects/gaxxxxxxxtor-xxxx420/traces/3e655015a967bfe8903db0ef5d1cfc7f"
}
```

Comment: Check the Cloud Run logs

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've edited my post with the logs of the 500 error...but I don't find find any clue :/

Comment: There should be more than that. However, it looks like your deployment has failed.

Comment: Could you please tell me where I can get more informations on this ? This is the first time I run CloudRun :/

Comment: Read the documentation. Google has extensive docs on Cloud Run, numerous examples and getting started guides. When you skip learning the basics, simple problems are hard to solve. My suggestion is to use one of the walk thoughts and deploy that to see how everything works. Also, review the docs on Cloud Logging. That is a vital service to know.

Comment: Did you try running your container on your desktop with Docker? Make sure that works first before trying to deploy.

Comment: Okay, I've created a Docker container on local and it seems that the error is :     raise Exception("No local .env or GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT detected. No secrets found."). Still, not sure if it's because it's  local.

Comment: I didn't encounter any errors when I followed the github link you provided. May I ask what are the changes have you done?

Comment: You will need to ensure that the database is connected to the service: `gcloud run services describe [servicename]`. This should have been configured by terraform, but none of the Cloud Build manifests reassert this. Enable Django's debugging by adding `DEBUG` as an envvar: `gcloud run services update [servicename] --set-env-vars DEBUG=true`